# Server side signature verification with php

Tags: php, android, openssl, rsa, in-app-billing

I have been struggling with signature verification of my app's products for weeks now. Upon purchase my app sends the purchase data and signature to a php server that is supposed to verify the signature. I have tried all kinds of different things to get it working but it just won't. I don't understand what is wrong with the code, maybe I'm sending wrong data or sending it wrongly.

I send the data to the server in the URL:

```
String query = "data="+data+"&sign="+signature;
URL url = new URL("siteurl/Verify.php?"+query);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
```

Where data and signature are:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    data = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
    signature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
}
```

The php code that is supposed to verify the signature:

```
$data = $_GET["data"];
$signature = $_GET["sign"];

$pkey = '[my public key from Google copy pasted]';
$key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" . chunk_split($pkey, 64, "\n") . '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';

$result = openssl_verify($data, base64_decode($signature), $key);
if($result == 0) {
    echo " fail ";
}

if($result == 1) { 
    echo " works ";
}
```

I have searched trough many pages to find a solution but nothing seems to work.
What am I doing wrong? Please, help.

EDIT: To be clearer the above php code always returns "fail" to my app.

Comment: why is there startactivityforresult?? have you decoded the echoed string??

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be the other way around: the server sends purchase information to the app? Otherwise, what stops bad guys from forging purchases?

Comment: @IllegalArgument OnActivityResult is called by buy intent which return the purchase information.

Comment: @jww The purchase data is signed with my private by Google on their servers. I'm checking if it is signed with my private key - if it isn't the purchase isn't legit.